# Taylor expansion for the Euler's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

I would like some help to show this: for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$e^{ix} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(ix)^k}{k!} + \theta \frac{|x|^n}{n!}$$
with some $\theta \in \mathbb{C}$, and $|\theta| \leq 1$.

I'm a lot confused because $e^{ix}$ is a complex function. I could try to use Taylor's expansion for the real case, but I would be lax. However, I know that $f(z)= e^z$ is analytic, then:
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} (z-z_0)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} (z-z_0)^k + \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} (z-z_0)^k $$
For $f(z)= e^z$, we have $f^{(n)}(z)= e^z$. Thus, for $z_0=0$  and $z = ix$, we have that $f^{(n)}(z_0)=1$ and:
$$e^{ix} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(ix)^k}{k!}  + \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(ix)^k}{k!} $$
But I can't conclude very rigorously.

Comment: Do you know Taylor's Theorem???

Comment: Dear, according wiki, $f(z)=P_k(z)+ R_k(z)$, $P_k = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{f^{j}(c)}{j!}(z-c)^j$, where the remainder term $R_k$ is complex analytic. I think this the same difficult. How to transform the remainder in $\theta \frac{|x|^n}{n!}$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: No, that's not Taylor's theorem. The theorem says much more about the remainder term. Look at the link you gave - look for the section "Statement of the Theorem".

Comment: In that section Statement of the Theorem, it only deals with the case of real functions: $e^t, \,\, t \in \mathbb{R}$. Really, I might be forgetting something basic to be allowed to go for $e^{it}$.

Comment: Ok. Scroll down - the one labelled "Integral forms of the remainder" is fine for complex-valued functions, trust me